# import @with_kw from Parameters inside my own package

Tags: module, macros, package, julia

I have created [my own Julia package](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/#Generating-files-for-a-package) and I am new to such practices.

I previously had this code:

```
using Parameters
@with_kw mutable struct MWE @deftype String
mwe1 = "default" ; @assert mwe1 in ["default", "1", "2"]
mwe2 = "test"
end
```

Which worked well. Now that I put it into my package, replacing `using` with `import`, I have the following error:

```
julia> import MyPackageMWE
[ Info: Precompiling RobustRSP [33e6bdf6-6d3e-458b-9f4e-8cd6eb784281]
[ Info: Loading JuMP
[ Info: Loading Gurobi
[ Info: Loading Combinatorics, DelimitedFiles, Dates and Random
[ Info: Loading Distributions, Graphs and Plots
[ Info: Loading Parameters and Formatting
[ Info: Loading Compose, Cairo and Fontconfig
[ Info: Loading .jl files   0%
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: @with_kw not defined
```

Any ideas what went wrong?
Maybe it is related to @macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the package Parameters but it may be that if @with_kw is exported in Parameters then if you replace

```
using Parameters
```

with

```
import Parameters
```

then you should change
`@with_kw` with `Parameters.@with_kw`